# C# WPF Login and Register with hashing and database

Tags: c#, wpf, hash, sha

**what I want to achieve:**

I want to make an account system with login and register. I already have the login and register system, this is also connected to the database. However, the passwords are not hashed.
I can't find any help on how to do the hashing in connection with the database.
In addition, I still wonder how I add a little salt, since this would be safer.

**Problem:**
See above

**code for login:**

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=xxxxx;Database=x;User Id=xxx;Password=xx;");
            try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();
                String query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblUser WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Password";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
```

### *Hash Stuff I want to implement*

**get SHA:**

```
private static byte[] GetSHA1(string userID, string password)
    {
    SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    return sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userID + password));
    }
```

**match SHA:**

```
private static bool MatchSHA1(byte[] p1, byte[] p2)
    {
    bool result = false;
    if (p1 != null && p2 != null)
        {
        if (p1.Length == p2.Length)
            {
            result = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < p1.Length; i++)
                {
                if (p1[i] != p2[i])
                    {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
    }
```

[test](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/186585/Password-Storage-How-to-do-it):

```
private static void RunTest()
    {
    string userId = "OriginalGriff";
    string password = "NotMyPassword";
    string enteredPassword = "NotMyPassword";
    string notPassword = "notMyPassword";
    byte[] hashedPassword = GetSHA1(userId, password);
    if (MatchSHA1(hashedPassword, GetSHA1(userId, enteredPassword)))
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Log him in!");
        }
    else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Don't log him in!");
        }
    if (MatchSHA1(hashedPassword, GetSHA1(userId, notPassword)))
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Will not happen!");
        }
    else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Don't log him in!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not hash your password as is and do not use Sha1. You should create a random salt and hash password +salt preferably with Sha256. Even better use pbkdf2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the passwords are not hashed. I can't find any help on how to do the hashing in connection with the database.

You are already familiar with how to store a string to the database here:

> `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);`

Since you know how to store the password as a `string` in the database, and you also know how to hash the password with `GetSHA1()` -  all we have to do is turn the hashed password into a `string`.

`GetSHA1` currently returns a `byte[]` which is the hashed password and username.

In order to turn the `byte[]` into a `string` we should *[Encode](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encode)*(format the bytes into human readable text) it from bytes into a `string`. We're going to use the [`System.Convert.ToBase64String()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0) method that takes any `byte[]` and turns it into a string.

Once we have encoded the hashed bytes into a `string` we don't have to use `MatchSHA1` any more and can delete that method. This is because we can compare `string`s with the `==` operator or using [other built-in methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings).

If we can turn the hash into a string instead of

```cs
if (MatchSHA1(hashedPassword, GetSHA1(userId, enteredPassword)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Log him in!");
}
```

we instead could use a much simpler

```cs
if (hashedPassword == SHA384(userId, enteredPassword))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Log him in!");
}
```

We can further strengthen the way we hash by upgrading to `SHA384` since `SHA1` is [no longer recommended for use because of it's high collision rate.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha1?view=net-5.0#remarks)

I went ahead and modified your `GetSHA1` method below with the recommended changes

```cs
private static string GetSHA384(string userID, string password)
{
    // SHA classes are disposable, use using to ensure any managed resources are properly disposed of by the runtime
    using SHA384 sha = new SHA384CryptoServiceProvider();

    // convert the username and password into bytes
    byte[] preHash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userID + password);

    // hash the bytes
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(preHash);

    // convert the raw bytes into a string that we can save to a database
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

In order to store the password just replace

> `sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);`

with the following

```cs
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", GetSHA384(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text));
```

> I still wonder how I add a little salt

#### If this is a passion project

`SHA` does not include an implementation of salting, for this you would have to make it yourself. I will leave this as an exercise for the reader or other helpful developers.

#### If this is a production project

I would recommend using an off-the-shelf implementation like BCrypt or something similar. Since implementing a secure salt and hash function yourself may lead to security vulnerabilities **I do not recommend self-implementing them**.

Comment: Sorry but, I am very new in this field and absolutely do not know how to implement the explanations. Could you possibly explain with some code? Especially the part with the login and comparison of the hashed password I do not understand. ("If we encode the hashed bytes into a string [...]")

Comment: I updated the post with more information and links to try and explain a little better

Comment: I understand the most part know, but isn't it 
`if (hashedPassword == GetSHA384(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Log him in!");
}`
Instead of 

`if (hashedPassword == SHA384(userId, enteredPassword))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Log him in!");
}`

also, it says that theres no "hashedPassword"